# getting the center of a google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using `com.google.android.maps.v2`

I am looking for a way to get the LatLng of the center of the viewable area of the map.

```
CustomMapFragment cusMapFrag;    
GoogleMap _map;
```

are set in my `onCreate` like so:

```
cusMapFrag = ((CustomMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map));    
_map = cusMapFrag.getMap();
```

I thought i use to be able to say `_map.getCenter()`; and that would return a lat and long for the center of the map view port.

I have tried: `_map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion()....` but there doesn't seem to be a `center` only: `nearLeft`, `nearRight`, `farLeft`, and `farRight`

Can anyone tell me how i can get the lat and long of the center of the viewable map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in my case the map is full screen, and i know my display width, height, and center. so this works for me:  `LatLng mapCenterLatLng = _map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(centerOfScreen);`

Answer (score 2):

do you try this it depend on the pixel hope it help you

```
GeoPoint mapCenter = cusMapFrag.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(
    mapView.getWidth()/2,
    mapView.getHeight()/2);
int lat = mapCenter.getLatitudeE6();
int lon = mapCenter.getLongitudeE6();
```

and this method you can get the Point on map

```
Point myPoint = toScreenLocation(LatLng) ;
```

Comment: It should be `cusMapFrag` instead of `mapView`. He is using either `MapFragment`or `SupportMapFragment`.

Comment: there is no fromPixels method available for _map.getProjection() and no getProjection() from mapFragment

Comment: @erik  first was google map version 1 and this method is deprecated and i edited the answer with the new version with google map version 2